# New to php and stick on error (parse error :syntax error, unexpected $'message' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

Start the session

```php
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION["Id"];
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
$pr = $_SESSION["profilepicture"];

include 'config/config.php';
include 'config/config1.php';
include 'config/connect.php';

$IDMail = $_POST['IDMail']
$Message = $_POST['Message']
$userid = $_POST['userid']

$time = time();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail (IDMail, IDUser, Time, Message) VALUES ('$IDMail','$IDUser','$time','$message')")  or die("error in insert please".mysql_error());
```

Comment: you have missed ';' after variable declaration like $IDMail =$_POST['IDMail']

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_*(). Use mysqli_*() or PDO instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860046#12860046)

Answer (score 1):

You've missed semicolon at the end of lines 11 to 13.

Answer (score 0):

All three lines where you assign $_POST attributes need a semicolon after them.

```
$IDMail =$_POST['IDMail']

$Message = $_POST['Message']

$userid = $_POST['userid']
```

should be

```
$IDMail =$_POST['IDMail'];

$Message = $_POST['Message'];

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
```

Comment: Well did exactly that and still being faced with errors like  undefined index:message.    Undefined variable :IDUser.   Undefined variable :time